# asp.net development server and AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, localhost

Is it possible to test some AJAX functions on a asp.net development server or do I need to upload the solution to a webserver and test it online ?

On my request.open method my url is "~/AjaxResponse.aspx?task=deleteCustomer&ID=4" and this won't work

http://localhost:1487/mydomain/AjaxResponse.aspx?task=deleteCustomer&ID=4 works

**Why is that ?**

Comment: Absolutely yes! You can test your web-app with dev web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IIS Developer Server provides you with everthing you need.

If you are using MS Ajax (with Script Manager etc), then just start your application from Visual Studio directly and put a breakpoint in the method that is called from your AJAX code -- and you can debug it.

Still, you can also use your own custom-written asynchronous queries in your code: as long as they are valid and the services you're requesting are up and running, you should get no error message.